Relative Import in Protobuf
Folder structure:

service.proto
    syntax = "proto3";

    package service;
    option go_package = "../../../proto-generated/user/service";
 
    import "user/models/models.proto";


    service UserService {
      rpc CreateUser(models.CreateUserRequest) returns (models.CreateUserResponse);
      rpc GetUser(models.GetUserRequest) returns (models.GetUserResponse);
    }

models.proto
    syntax = "proto3";

    package models;
    option go_package = "../../../proto-generated/user/models";

    message CreateUserRequest {
      string username = 1;
      int32 age = 2;
    }

    message CreateUserResponse {
      int32 id = 1;
    }

    message GetUserRequest {
      int32 id = 1;
    }

    message GetUserResponse {
      int32 id = 1;
      string username = 2;
      int32 age = 3;
    }

I tried to create proto files using
protoc -I=. --go_out=. models.proto

and
protoc -I=. --go-grpc_out=. service.proto
by going in respective directory,
models proto is getting created successfully, as it doesn't contain any import, however service generation is failing

error: user/models/models.proto: File not found.


There are no relative imports in Go, use the actual import path.

You don't do relative imports in Protocol Buffers.
try something like
protoc -I=proto-message --go_out=proto-generated --go_opt=paths=source_relative proto-message/user/*/*.proto

in the root ouf your source and choose sane package names, like
import "user/models/models.proto";

option go_package = "your.module.here/proto-generated/user/service";

Importing Definitions

The protocol compiler searches for imported files in a set of
directories specified on the protocol compiler command line using the
-I/--proto_path flag. If no flag was given, it looks in the
directory in which the compiler was invoked. In general you should set
the --proto_path flag to the root of your project and use fully
qualified names for all imports.

See also “Compiler Invocation” in the Go Generated Code Guide.
Also, from “Changes announced for Protocol Buffers on April 20, 2023”:

This is a user error: each import should always be referred to by a
consistent full path.

